# How to set Sender Address in flow's "core action"

Tags: email, visual-workflow

I am struggling to set the sender address when sending a simple email using the Flow's core email action.  No matter what I put in the sender address field, the running user's email (my email) appears as the sender.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The core Send Email action doesn't support an arbitrary email address for the sender - the only possible senders are the user running the flow, the default workflow user, or an organization-wide email address.

Changing the `Sender Type` will change the default (the current user, as you're seeing) to one of the other possible sender types. The `Sender Address` is only used to specify an org-wide email address.

From the [Flow Core Action: Send Email](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_elements_actions_sendemail.htm&type=5) docs:

> `Sender Address`: The organization-wide email address that's used to
>   send the email. Required only if the `Sender Type` is set to
>   `OrgWideEmailAddress`.
>
> `Sender Type`: Optional. Email address used as the email's From and
>   Reply-To addresses. Valid values are:
>
> - `CurrentUser` - Email address of the user running the flow (Default)
> - `DefaultWorkflowUser` - Email address of the default workflow user
> - `OrgWideEmailAddress` - The organization-wide email address that is specified in Sender Address.

=======

Comment: Thank you!  That was the clarification I needed.  I was putting an organization-wide address in the sender address field, but I wasn't setting the type to OrgWideEmailAddress.