# From Address for outbound email message in experience cloud

Tags: community, email

We have a requirement to set the from address to the outbound emails sending from communities like welcome, forgot password and reset password.

Currently it's taking the email address which we provided in the community administration page.

One solution i thought for this is configuring org-wide email addresses, but it's not working.

Apart from this is there any solution or am i missing anything configuring for org wide email addresses

Any Suggestion/Solution are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have it sending using the email you provided but instead want it to link to the Org Wide Default Address? I haven't seen anything to suggest that the OrgWideDefault can be utilized there but you can simply manually enter the same information in the Administration page for the experience to match the OrgWideDefault. See this [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_customize_email.htm&type=5) on the Email settings setup.

This applies to the emails sent by the Experience site itself, such as those you mention. However, if you are using custom buttons, flows, and/or email alerts to send them it will be best to use an OrgWideDefault. Take a look at these articles for [email alert/OrgWideDefault](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/cma_customize_email_org_wide_address.htm) setup and [flow email send](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/291455/how-to-set-sender-address-in-flows-core-action) info.